# scanf lee valor incorrecto

Tags: c, scanf

Me encuentro con un problema que no logro entender y es con respecto a un "scanf" que estoy utilizando  en C++.
El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i, n, overtakes, start[26], finish[26];

    while(scanf("%d", &n) != EOF);{
        printf("%d\n", n);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            scanf("%d", &start[i]);         
            printf("%d ", start[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            scanf("%d", &finish[i]);    
        }
        overtakes = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(start[i] < finish[i]){
                overtakes = overtakes+(finish[i]-start[i]);
        }   
    }
    //printf("%d\n", overtakes);        
}
return 0;
}
```

Mi problema aquí es que no entiendo por que el primer "scanf" no parece recibir la entrada adecuada ya que al pedirle que imprima "n" y los valores del arreglo "start" (como prueba) con la siguiente entrada:

```
9
7 1 8 9 5 6 2 3 4
8 1 9 5 7 3 2 6 4
```

obtengo:

```
13
204196 6422220 1952017685 1952334620 6422284 
1952014984 8 1951951811 1951951802 1994325155 4199136 4199136 0
```

Aprecio cualquier ayuda y/o colaboración.

Answer (score 1):

Has introducido un ';' al final del while:

```
//                           vvv
while(scanf("%d", &n) != EOF) ; {
```

Con ese ';' estás haciendo que sólo se ejecute la condición del while, es decir:

```
while(scanf("%d", &n) != EOF);   // <------- Se ejecuta scanf hasta el final de la entrada

// Al acabar el while, ejecuta una sóla vez lo que hay entre llaves, pues está fuera del while:
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &start[i]); 
    ...
    ...
```